# WP - Incorrect Resource URL

Tags: resource-urls

WordPress Version: 5.2.2 | CiviCRM - Version 5.15.2 | shared hosting situation with shell access

I've reviewed the various similar questions, but none of them has revealed the answer for me, so I'm posting here. How can I make this error go away? What am I missing?

I click on System Status: Error at the bottom of the UI and get this:

**Incorrect Resource URL**
The Resource URL is not set correctly. Please set the CiviCRM Resource URL.

So I go to the link to set the CiviCRM Resource URL and see this:

**URL Variables:**

[cms.root]  https://mysite.org/

[civicrm.root]  https://mysite.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/

[civicrm.files] https://mysite.org/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/

These variables are computed automatically using civicrm.settings.php and its options, such as CIVICRM_TEMPLATE_COMPILEDIR.

CiviCRM Resource URL    [civicrm.root]/

Image Upload URL    [civicrm.files]/persist/contribute/

Custom CSS URL          blank

Disable CiviCRM css     Yes     x No

Extension Resource URL  [civicrm.files]/ext/

Force Secure URLs (SSL) x Yes   No

Verify SSL Certs    x Yes   No

Settings in civicrm.settings.php seem to be correct.

```
$civicrm_root = '/home/myuser/mysite.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/';
define( 'CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL'      , 'http://mysite.org/' );
```

Comment: Is anything broken?  This could be a false positive.  Check the Network tab in your Developer Tools in your web browser, look for anything that doesn't come back "OK", particularly CSS and JavaScript files.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Status 200 across the board, no red flags in the network tab, although there is this red flag in the console: "Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received. -- /wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fa%2F#/status:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received."

Comment: I wrote this particular check, and it's caused a lot of false positives, so I feel a responsibility to reply to folks who are getting them (and ideally eliminate the problem).  Based on your error message, I'm wondering if the System Status page is loading?  You can compare it to the one here: https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/a/#/status.  If not, this isn't a false positive.  If it is, I'll try to investigate what could cause that error.

Comment: Again, thanks for your response. This page: /wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fa%2F#/status gives this status: https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/48474708376_e1807e0e83_o.jpg

Comment: Also, nothing seems broken, so it's possible it's a false positive.

Comment: If nothing is broken, it's fine to just click "Never show me this again".  If at some point you stumble across the reason it's happening, please reply here - I really want to squeeze out the false positives!

Comment: Same for me (also older CiviCRM 5.14.2). At some point in time the error occured without any noticable malfunction or network Status error.. @JonG-MegaphoneTech, does ist make sense to describe, what this check tests in particular?

Comment: @Weidenrinde That's an excellent idea.  Some of us were discussing ensuring that every error on the status page have a dedicated page in the documentation with additional info; maybe this page should be the test case.

Comment: In my case, the error message was triggered by a shift from php 7.2 to php 7.3 and possible installation mistakes on my webhoster.

Comment: Hey guys, any chance to improve this check? I've tried everything I've seen on this topic on StackExchange, and then some, but am still getting the error pop-up. Yes, I can click "never show me this again", but that won't remove it for other users, correct? Plus in CiviCRM footer, it keeps showing "System Status: Error" with red background. Doesn't instill user confidence in the system + makes us complacent, i.e. ignoring warnings 'coz they're false positives - well, what if there are true issues that would get ignored? Thanks much for your consideration.